# Recreating merge-with

Tags: clojure

Just working through the questions on 4Clojure as I learn the language. This is my solution for #69. Would appreciate feedback as this one gave me a little trouble.

```
(fn merge-with2 [f m & ms]
   (let [update-or-add (fn update-or-add [m1 k f arg] 
                          (let [x (get m1 k)]
                            (if (nil? x)
                              (conj m1 {k arg})
                              (update-in m1 [k] f arg))))]
   (loop [m1 m m2 (first ms) ms ms
          k (keys m2)]
     (if-not (map? m2)
       m1
       (recur (reduce #(update-or-add %1 %2 f (get m2 %2)) m1 k)
              (first (next ms))
              (next ms)
              (keys (first (next ms))))))))
```

I suspect that it would be possible to replace the `loop/recur` with a nested `reduce`, but I'm not quite sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are my thoughts:

### `letfn` instead of `let`

You could use [`letfn`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/letfn) instead of `let`, which would be a little more concise:

```
(letfn [(update-or-add [m1 k f arg]
          ...
```

### conj vs. update-in

`conj` and `update-in` are very similar functions in that they both take a map and "update" the value for a key that may or may not exist. Because of this, they are sometimes exchangeable. `update-in` is fine here, but I think using `conj` for both scenarios could make it easier to see at a glance what your function is doing. (See the next example.)

### `if-let`

The `(let [x (get m1 k)] (if (nil? x) ...` part of your code is a good example of where [`if-let`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/if-let) comes in handy.

```
(if-let [x (m1 k)]
  (conj m1 {k (f x arg)})
  (conj m1 {k arg}))
```

Which you could even simplify further by moving the `if-let` inside of a single `conj` function call:

```
(conj m1 {k (if-let [x (m1 k)] (f x arg) arg)})
```

As an aside, I tend to prefer `assoc`, although it's really just as good as `conj`:

```
(assoc m1 k (if-let [x (m1 k)] (f x arg) arg))
```

### Reducers work best as functions taking 2 arguments

The first thing I noticed about your `loop` is that its arguments can be simplified:

```
(loop [m1 m, ms ms]
  ...
```

Essentially what you're doing is starting with `m1` and reducing `update-or-add` over each key-value pair in each map in `ms`. The tricky thing here is that, as you pointed out, this is a nested reducing operation, in that each map in `ms` can have multiple key-value entries. You have the right general idea in that you have a `reduce` within a `loop`, but a better/simpler way to do this would be to make your `update-or-add` function take the two arguments that a reducing function expects -- an accumulator and the next item in the collection being reduced over. Once you have `update-or-add` working that way, you can do the same thing with your loop and at that point you'll be able to represent your solution as a simple nested `reduce`.

Let's start with `update-or-add`. This function takes a working "map in progress" and a key-value pair and either adds it to the map if that key isn't already there, or it updates the value to be the result of calling `f` with the value already there and the new value as arguments. Note that we don't need to make `f` an argument because it's already available within the context of the entire function `merge-with2`. You can also use [destructuring](http://blog.jayfields.com/2010/07/clojure-destructuring.html) to easily access the key and the value of the key-value pair.

```
(letfn [(update-or-add [m1 [k v]]
          (assoc m1 k (if-let [x (m1 k)] 
                        (f x v) 
                        v)))]
  ...
```

Now you can use `update-or-add` "as-is" within a `reduce`.

You can do something similar with your main loop. To simplify things, let's make it its own function, and call it something like `merge-with-one`. This function will take one of the maps supplied to `merge-with2` and reduce `update-or-add` over its key-value pairs. Defining this function is actually super easy, because it's just a call to `reduce`. So, here is my suggested refactoring of your code:

```
(fn merge-with2 [f m & ms]
  (letfn [(update-or-add [m1 [k v]]
            (assoc m1 k (if-let [x (m1 k)] 
                          (f x v) 
                          v)))
          (merge-with-one [m1 m2]
            (reduce update-or-add m1 m2))]
    (reduce merge-with-one m ms)))
```

It turns out that this is actually pretty close to [the actual implementation of `merge-with` in clojure.core](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L2915).